# How to fetch the json array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have my external json and trying to fetch the json values dynamically in my javascript. I am able to fetch the first level values and when I try to fetch the array object, it is showing my result as undefined. However when I try this  **"alert(data.siteAttribute[0].data[0].label);"** its returning the the value.

Here is the following that I have tried

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/naqzj", function(data) { 
 
   $(".test").html('<div class="card-deck">');
    var output = "";
    for (var i in data.siteAttribute) {
  output += "<div class='col-md-4 col-lg-3'><div class='card  site-attribute-card'>";
  
  output += "<span class='sticker sticker-rounded sticker-top-right'><span class='inline-item'><img height='50' width='50' src='"+data.siteAttribute[i].data.imageURL +"'/></span></span>";
  
  output += "<div class='card-body'> <div class='card-row'>"
        output +="<div class='card-title text-truncate'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].data.label + "</div>";
        output += "<div class='card-text'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].data.value + "</div>";
  output +="<div class='card-title text-truncate'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].data.operatinghours + "</div>";
        output += "<div class='card-text'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].data.hours + "</div>";
  output +="<div class='card-title text-truncate'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].data.areaLabel + "</div>";
        output += "<div class='card-text'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].data.areaValue + "</div>";
  output +="<div class='card-title text-truncate'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].dateModified + "</div>";
        output +="<div class='card-text'>" + data.siteAttribute[i].date + "</div>";
  output += "</div></div>"; 
  
  output += "<div class='card-footer'>";
  output += "<div class='card-title text-truncate' title='Card Title'>"+ data.siteAttribute[i].name + "<span class='label label-tag label-category right'><span class='label-item label-item-expand'>"+data.siteAttribute[i].status+"</span></span></div>";
  output += "<div class='card-links'><a href='/group/retail/site-management-form'>Edit</a><a class='right' href='#'>View</a></div></div>"
  output += "</div></div>";    
 }
    $(".test .card-deck").append(output); 
    $(".test .card-deck").append('</div>'); 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test container">
</div>
```

Here is my sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn4Lafte/2/) for reference. I am missing the loop fro the array and have no clues on how to figure out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an array in your array - so you need 2 loops

Comment: Could you help me out on how to add the second loop in the fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are only having issues with having nested loops. To loop over an array of objects I suggest I suggest using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). To simplify your demo I have removed all the HTML markup and nested two `forEach` loops to parse over the JSON data. Please review the demo and inline comments below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/naqzj", function(result) {
    // Loop over the top level attributes
    result.siteAttribute.forEach(function(attr) {
      // Loop over the attribute `data` array
      attr.data.forEach(function(attrData) {
        // For demo purposes, loop over the inner data object and print its props and values
        for (var key in attrData) {
          console.log(key, ' -> ', attrData[key]);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`data.siteAttribute[i].data` is an array

So you can use `data.siteAttribute[i].data[0]` to get the first item or you'll have to loop through that data as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am not sure that I am using it in the right way. Here is what I have tried as a second loop " for (var j in data.siteAttribute.data){.. }" but its not showing anything